# insertBefore does not work

Tags: javascript

I am using this code trying to add new content before another element:

```
 var form = document.getElementsByClassName('commentresponse')[0],
     newcomment = '<div><span></span><span><p class="author">'+author+'</p><p class="content">'+comment+'</p></span></div>' ;
 form.insertBefore(newcomment, form);
```

The 2 vars work fine and return what I expect. However Chrome gives me this error: `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`

Somehow the insertBefore line blocks the code. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertBefore` takes a DOM node, not HTML.

Do this instead:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('commentresponse')[0],
    newcomment = document.createElement('div');
newcomment.innerHTML = '<span></span><span><p class="author">'+author+'</p><p class="content">'+comment+'</p></span>';
form.parentNode.insertBefore(newcomment, form);
```

You will want to escape `author` and `comment`, as strings which contain `'<'`, `'>'`, and `'&'` will mess it up.

For completeness, here's how you could do it completely with DOM nodes (without using `innerHTML` -- although doing such things seems to be a lost art on the modern web):

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('commentresponse')[0],
    newcomment = document.createElement('div'),
    el, el2;
newcomment.appendChild(document.creatElement('span'));
el = document.createElement('span');
el2 = document.createElement('p');
el2.className = 'author';
el2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(author));
el.appendChild(el2);
el2 = document.createElement('p');
el2.className = 'content';
el2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
el.appendChild(el2);
newcomment.appendChild(el);
form.parentNode.insertBefore(el, form);
```

This way doesn't need to be escaped, since `author` and `content` are explicitly added as text nodes.

Comment: Wouldn't this post newcomment inside of "form" instead of before?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize you wanted it before. I have adjusted my answer.